# Trouble developing on mirrored, but separate, production environment

Tags: continuous-integration, docker, development-environment, virtualization, lxc

I'm having some problems with the "development environment should be as close as possible to the production environment".

*(Production machine's operating system is Linux.)*

### My understanding of development steps (roughly):

- *code, compile, test/run, repeat*

"Normally" I would go through these on my own machine, then push the code to CI for testing, and possibly deploy. The CI would be responsible for running the tests in an environment that matches production, this way if the tests pass, it's safe to assume that the code works in production as well.

### The problem of a larger environment

☑ Database - of some kind.
☑ Job Processing Pool - for some long-running background tasks.
☑ User Account Management - used by other systems as well.
☑ Centralized Logging - for sanity.
☑ Forward Proxy - to tie individual http-accessible services under the same url but different paths.
☐ And possible other services or collections of services.

*Solutions?*

- All on my own machine? *No way in hell.*
- All on a virtual machine? Maybe, but security-wise if this setup was supposed to mirror the prod.env., and the prod.env. was like this, well.. that might not be such a good idea in case of a breach.
- Divide by responsibility and set them up on multiple virtual machines? Who's gonna manage all those machines? I think it's possible to do better than this.
- Use containers such as Docker, or slap similar together by yourself? Sounds good: (Possibly:) very fast iteration cycles, separation of concern, some security by separation, and easy reproducibility.

*For the sake of simplicity, let's say that our containerization tooling of choice is Docker, and we are not going to build one ourselves with libvirt / lxc tooling / direct kernel calls.*

So Docker it is, possibly with CoreOS or Project Atomic. So now there is a container for an application (or multiple applications) that has been separated from the rest of the system, and can be brought up nearly identically anywhere.

- Solution number 1: Production environment is pretty and elegant.
- Problem number 1: This is not development environment.

### The development environment

Whatever the choice to not having to sprinkle the production environment into my own machine, the problem remains the same:

*Even though the production environment is correctly set up, I have to run the compilation and testing somewhere, before being able to deploy (be it to another testing round by CI or whatever).*

How do I solve this?

Can it really be that the proper way to solve this is by writing code on my own machine, having it synchronized/directly visible in a virtualized-mirrored-production-like environment, which automates running of the tests?

What happens when I don't want to run all the tests, but only the portion that I'm writing right now? Do I edit the automated compilation process every time? What about remote debugging, since multiple systems must be orchestrated to run in the correct way, and debugging must attach in-between to one of the programs. Not to mention the speed of "*code, test*" cycle, which would be _very_ slow.

This sounds helluvalot like CI, but multiple developers can't all use the same CI and modify it, so they probably have to have this setup on their own machines.

I was also thinking that the developers could each use a completely virtualized os that contained all the development tools and was mirrored environment-wise with the production, but that would force veteran users to adopt the tooling of the virtual development environment, which doesn't sound such a good idea.

Comment: Not entirely clear what question you're asking. You appear to be outlining a case for an exception to the rule. My comment would be to note the "as possible" part of the statement. The more like production your development is the more likely your tests will find issues before they get released. It's not easy, especially for a legacy system, but I would hesitate to say it's impossible. In an ideal world, the only thing that should differentiate between Dev and Prod is the applications' data.